# How to substitute $\log_{10}$ for $\ln$ function?

Tags: logarithms

Im wondering how I could go about substituting $\log_{10}$ for $\ln$ in the following formula?

$y=a+b\ln(x+c)$

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean substitute log10 for ln? Or is did you typo the equation?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For any $\;1\neq a,b>0\;$ :

$$\log_ax=\frac{\log_bx}{\log_ba}$$

Comment: Still struggling im afraid. Im at a loss at how to apply this change of base to the equation Ive got.

Comment: @Ke., your function is not clear at all. I can't help you with that, but I think the above is pretty clear, isn't it? Of course, you need to read about logarithms a little. The above's called "property of change of basis in logarithms". You can even google it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a a formula to change from base $k$ to base $b$. See [$\log_b x=\dfrac{\log_k x}{\log_k b}.$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base)

In your equation you have $\log(x+c)$ ($\log$ is the natural logarithm). If we apply the change of base rule we get:

$$\log(x+c)=\dfrac{\log_{10}(x+c)}{\log_{10} e},$$

where $e=\exp(1)$ is the exponetial of $1$ [$e=2.71828$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29).

Therefore your equation is simply:

$$y=a+\dfrac{b}{\log_{10} e}\log_{10}(x+c),$$

Comment: I sort of get how to change base, but just not sure how to apply this to the equation I have :/

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer.